# Editing files using elftoolchain

Tags: elf

I have managed to use [elftoolchain](https://sourceforge.net/p/elftoolchain/wiki/Home/) to read ELF files, but I am having trouble editing ELF files.

I tried opening the ELF file using:

```
Elf *elf = elf_begin( ELF_C_RDWR, NULL);
```

I then just do nothing to the ELF object and then to write it back out I call:

```
elf_update(elf, ELF_C_WRITE);
```

I end up with a corrupted ELF file.

Note: I am using elftoolchain 0.6.1 as the install process for version 0.7.1 seems to overwrite the system ld.

Bonus: does anyone know how to write the elf file out to a different file descriptor from the one from which it was read in?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can use C++, just use this library instead: https://github.com/serge1/ELFIO